# pandas.read_html() is taking too long to return the list of tables lately, if the html size is > 5 mb

Tags: python, html, pandas

pandas.read_html() is taking too long to return the list of tables lately, if the  html size is > 5 mb. if there are only a couple of tables pd.read_html() return the list instantly but if has 10 tables then its taking forever. this was never a problem before. i built my entire project based on this. and now everything's a bust because somewhere something blew up internally and no one seems to be bothered. I cannot give any data( confidential else i wouldn't have a problem and am unable to find any websites hat have multiple tables(>5) in a single page. There are either one or two tables or images of the tables.) to duplicate the code but can explain how to recreate it.

```
import pandas as pd

file=r'_path_to_html_file' # this file should be a large (>5 mb with mutliple tables >5) 
#else the problem wont be triggered

tables=pd.read_html(file)
# this will return a list within a second usually a couple of months ago when i finished my project.
#but of late it takes forever(>30-40 minutes for a 16 mb html file) to do so.
```

Comment: Use selenium to web scraping that is much faster..

Comment: What is the size of Memory on the system you running this operation?

Comment: I have html file of 5 MB with `[13895 rows x 13 columns]`  it takes only  minute to process?

Comment: @min2bro will try. although i found another way around  the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @pygo its runnig on an 8 gb  machine. even when it was runnign fast it was the same system.

Comment: @pygo can you share the html?  and the version of pandas? thank you.